# Need to access an element from part of a string array

Tags: c++, string, char

Suppose I have this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string disectedString[5];

    disectedString[0] = "011001";

    string temp = disectedString[0];
    string print = temp[0];

    return 0;
}
```

So I'm selecting an element out of my array of strings, and then assigning it to a temp variable. From there, I want to select the first element out of the temp variable,(the first character). How would I go about doing this?

Comment: Have you considered reading [the documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string)?

Comment: `temp` is a `std::string`. Elements of `std::string` are `char`, not another `std::string`.

Comment: I'd suggest you start by reading [a good book](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list). Trial and error is not a good method for learning C++ :)

Comment: Other than using the wrong type for `print` your program does do what you wanted to.

Comment: Haven't you already done it?

Answer (score 2):

Your intuition is mostly valid: You use the square brackets operator, `[]`, to access the element at an indexed position within a collection or sequence. Thus

- `disectedString[0]` means "the first element of disectedString";
- `temp[0]` means "the first element of temp";

What you've gotten mixed up are the types, as commenters and @demogorgon.net's answer have explained.

Now, with modern C++ you can "play dumb" and not declare what you know the types to be:

```
std::string disectedString[5];
disectedString[0] = "011001";
auto temp = disectedString[0];
auto print = temp[0];
```

Note the use of `auto` instead of a specific type name. This will work as you would like it to. You can then use use `print`, and do, for example:

```
std::cout << print;
```

and this will output `0`.

---

By the way, I believe you should reconsider your choice of names:

- Intuitively, `print` should refer to a function, or a method, which prints things; I'd suggest `first_character` or `char_to_print` or just `c` if you want to be brief.
- `temp` is no more a temporary variable than, say, `print`.
- It's better to avoid variable names which contain the type name, although we sometimes sort of have to resort to that. Specifically  you using the word 'string' in variable names; probably not a good idea.
- Your `disectedString` variable is not a string, it's an array of strings, which is confusing.

Answer (score 1):

A `string` behaves in many ways like an array of `char`'s (*).  You need to set `print` to `char` type instead of `string` since you are trying to get a specific element from the `string`. So your `print` should look like this:

`char print = temp[0];`

<sub>(*) but it's really more complicated than that.</sub>

Here is a code example that [prints the output](http://cpp.sh/4vh7q).

Comment: I wouldn't really say `std::string`s are essentially arrays of `char`s. They behave like them to some extent.

Comment: @einpoklum yes that's correct. I only say essentially because on the most basic level, this is easy to comprehend for someone learning c++. but you are right :)

Comment: Also, why do you insist OP used `temp.at()` instead of `temp[0]`? The latter is [perfectly valid code](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at).

Comment: ughh you are right, idk why to be honest, especially after I just said its like an array of `chars`. editing it now. @einpoklum